# KeyboardType numeric is not working in React native iPad

Tags: ipad, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm implementing an App only for iPad and apparently react native doesn't support numeric keyboard type for iPad. just want to know any idea how to manage keyboard to show only numbers.
I tried some regular expression but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this is not supported for Ipad. So you will need to either:

1) Show non-numeric characters but only accept numeric characters (via code).

2) Use this library [react-native-custom-keyboard](https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-custom-keyboard).

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
keyboardType = 'number-pad'
```

Hope it works

Or read some [article](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype)